# @controlleradvice giving error : scope 'session' is not active for current thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, controller-advice

I am facing an issue with Spring mvc annotation **@Controlleradvice**.
I have 2 controller classes: **UserGapsController** and **RegistrationBaseController**
Both classes use

1. @Controller
2. @Controlleradvice
3. @Autowired session object
4. @Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)

@Controlleradvice annotation has to be used when **@Modelattribute** is used at method level. So i am having a method annotated with @Modelattribute in both classes.
Now problem is when i am using @Controlleradvice in just UserGapsController.java , application runs fine , when i use @Controlleradvice in RegistrationBaseController.java also , it breaks down at runtime with following error:

***error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.requestmappinghandler: invocation of init method failed:nested exceotion is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException :Error creating bean with name 'userGapsController' : Scope 'session' is not active for current thread***

What is the reason for this error , can not we have 2 @Controlleradvice annotated classes ? When I comment @Controlleradvice in RegistrationBaseController.java , it executes fine then.

Comment: If you want two classes two have @controlleradvice then simply add @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) annotation. It will work

Comment: @ArunPrasat Sorry if i sound stupid , but i am new to spring. so we cant have 2 classes having  controlleradvice annotation ? if yes , the what is the logic behind ? My understanding was controlleradvice is used where we use ModelAttribute at method level. Is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: > @Controlleradvice annotation has to be used when @Modelattribute is used at method level. That isn't true, an `@ModelAttribute` works in a regular controller perfectly fine. Only if you want an `@ModeLAttribute` method that applies to all controller then you  need an `@ControllerAdvice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to have multiple `@ControllerAdvice` classes that handle different exceptions.

You can use Order over controllerAdvice like this

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RegistrationExceptionHandler {

    //...

}
```

and

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE) // or any int value
public class UserGapsExceptionHandler {

    //...

}
```

Comment: Sorry if i sound stupid , but i am new to spring. so we cant have 2 classes having  controlleradvice annotation ? if yes , the what is the logic behind ? My understanding was controlleradvice is used where we use ModelAttribute at method level. Is my understanding wrong ?